# All programs crash after trying to save on desktop

Tags: windows-7, crash

I used to have a problem in saving with Google Chrome, the problem is whenever I want to save something in the Desktop, Chrome crashes. Now I have this problem with all programs. Whenever I try to save something to the Desktop, the program crashes...

Any one has an idea on how to solve this?

**UPDATE1**

There is no errors when the programs crash, and there is nothing either in the Event Viewer.

Comment: update programs... try anti-virus...

Comment: All programs are up to date and I have an antivirus

Comment: try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is too vague. More details are needed. Are there any error messages? If so, what are they? Are there any events in the Event Viewer related to this which can help troubleshoot? Please also tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. It may be helpful to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: How do they crash? Is there an error message?

Comment: I've updated the topic with more information.. @HemantRupani I will run the test and update the topic

Comment: Sounds like a Windows anomaly... What does your Desktop folder contain (including hidden files)?

Comment: @oldmud0, the desktop contains only my files (some folders, jpegs and word documents) there is no hidden files!

Comment: Not even a desktop.ini?

Comment: @oldmud0 no there is no desktop.ini... desktop.ini is present in every folder, but not in the Desktop.. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/278503/open-save-as-causing-programs-to-crash-on-windows-7), the problem seems to be caused by network discovery. Try going to Network and Sharing Center, go to `Advanced sharing settings`, and check `Turn off network discovery`.

It could also be caused by a problem with loading thumbnails, or a network drive that is hung up.

Comment: I tried it, but I still have the same problem :/

Comment: As I said, these are Windows anomalies, the hardest and quirkiest problems to fix. You're just going to have to gather some more info, I guess..