# Open and Save as dialog crashing programs

Tags: windows, freeze, crash

Im really not sure what is causing this, I only encountered the program since I updated to Windows 10. Whenever I try to save or open a file in any program (except chrome and MS Word if its in safe mode) then the program will lock up and "has stopped responding" I had this problem last year on Windows 8 but when I bought a SSD i reinstalled windows so the problem was obviously fixed. But now its back again and I can't figure out what's causing it. Any help? I have tried googling but most results are either unrelated or are microsoft's support page spitting out the same useless things that don't work. I did find this user that had the same problem on Windows 7. ["Open"/"Save As" causing programs to crash on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/278503/open-save-as-causing-programs-to-crash-on-windows-7) Its happened to me on Notepad, Notepad++, MSPaint, MSWord (except when in safe mode) a usb iso burner called Rufus and Snipping Tool.

Comment: I assume you have ruled out this being caused by a network drive?

Comment: We had a network drive but its been disconnected since before I installed earlier this year. Also I just found out what was causing it. After trying different things including a registry cleaner It turned out to be OldNewExplorer that I installed back in February. Uninstalled and restarted now I can save files again. If only I had found it was that sooner.

Comment: You should answer your own question when given the chance to do so.

Comment: Please don't add [Solved] to question title. If you've found a solution, post it as an answer and mark it as accepted (you'll have to wait 48 hours). This will mark your question as resolved and the answer will be clearly visible for everyone.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to do that, this is the first time I've posted something, sorry

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by OldNewExplorer. Uninstalling fixed it